# Ajax responses whole pagecode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to simply get a variable from javascript to php, but php doesnt receive my variable - instead it receives the whole page-code.

Here is my test-page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button").click(function() {
          var test = "Hallo Welt";
          $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
              test: test
            },
            success: function (response) {
              alert(response);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="button" id="button" value="Test" style="width:200x">
    </form>

    <?php
      if(isset($_POST["test"])) {
        echo $_POST["test"];
      }
    ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have an hint?

greetings

Comment: please show the ajax code..

Comment: It starts in line 8 - doesn t it?

Comment: Can your **[fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/)** it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to have a separate PHP file that processes the AJAX request, though there would be benefits from doing so. If you had a separate file, let's say called 'data.php', you could set that script up in such a way so that it could process many different requests - each time you call your ajax function the url would be the same ( `data.php` ) but the parameters sent in the request would change.

The `exit` statement below is only encountered for `POST` requests and prevents the remainder of the html being sent back to your javascript callback function.

```
<?php
    /* Intercept the POST request, do whatever processing required and echo a response */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        /* Remove any previous output from our reply */
        ob_clean();

        /* send the response */
        if( isset( $_POST["test"] ) ) echo $_POST["test"];

        /* The `exit` statement prevents the rest of the page being sent in response */
        exit(); 
    }
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>

          $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#button").click(function() {
              var test = "Hallo Welt";
              $.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                  test: test
                },
                success: function (response) {
                  alert(response);
                  document.getElementById('out').innerHTML=response;
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
              });
            });
          });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="button" id="button" value="Test" style="width:200x">
      <output id='out'></output>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1st its better to use your php code in a separated file

2nd if you want to use it in the same file like you doing here your code should be

3rd use form.on('submit') instead of submit button click

4th don't forget to add (e) and e.preventDefault(); or return false

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["test"])) {
       echo $_POST["test"];
    }else{
 ?>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").on('submit',function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var test = "Hallo Welt";
          $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
              test: test
            },
            success: function (response) {
              alert(response);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="button" id="button" value="Test" style="width:200x">
    </form>


  </body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: 1st: Does a seperate php-file navigate the user on another page?
2st: Thanks!
3st: Thanks! I ll have several buttons, so i changed the type of the neccessary button to "submit". It works fine!
4st: Is it also important if i use button click?

I prefer the PHP-solution with 
`if($SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST){`
because i haven't splitted my whole html-code into an else-query.

though nice work! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use separate php file first of all, then add **exit;** after php **echo** line,

```
    <?php
          if(isset($_POST["test"])) {
            echo $_POST["test"];
            exit;
          }
        ?>
```

check and let me know if anything is missing.

Thanks.

Comment: Does a seperate file send the user on another page?

Comment: No, It will be a background process! so user will not redirect to any other page.